# Save unicode web page by c#

Tags: c#, webrequest

I use below code to save an utf-8 web page :

```
    HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(txtUrl.Text);
    myWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1);Accept-Language:fa";
    WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
    string strResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    StreamWriter oSw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\ehsan.html");
    oSw.WriteLine(strResponse);
    oSw.Close();
    readStream.Close();
    myWebResponse.Close();  
    txtUrl.Text = strResponse;
```

But in ehsan.html file and txtUrl all unicode characters are symbols. Is my solution is correct? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Are you able to advise the source URL?  Or is it all URLs?

Comment: http://asnaf.ir/directory.php?guildid=12731

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you're loading contains:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">`

So if you change your code to this:

`Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");`

it works. (I've tested) :-)

Whether or not you want to hard-code the encoding is up to you, and would depend on if you're only loading from the same page or pages with different encodings.

Comment: @Ehsan-Sadeghi You might also want to check out [The MSDN article on the `HttpRequest.TransferEncoding` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.transferencoding.aspx) as this _might_ allow you to collect the correct encoding from the site's header. (Thanks for accepting!)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use "Arabic" instead of UTF-8 for your Encoding
```